# Docker commit: why aren't my own image "changeble"

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

"docker commit" works on changes for a "ubuntu" image but not my own image. Why is there a difference?

Details:

I tried to modify container and commit it back to a new image. It works well when I try with "Ubuntu:latest" image:

> docker run --name test -it Ubuntu:latest
>   "some changes in files inside ......"
>   docker commit test  my_new_image

But when I try the exact same thing on the images made by me, the changes don't apply to the new image.

Based on other answers, I may need to mount the "volume" to make changes, but how does the "Ubuntu" image get rid of the volume? Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: As a recommendation, you should avoid the update -> commit model. If you need to make changes, create a new Dockerfile and inherit the previous image to make it reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @Dockstar, that's how I do usually. In few cases I only need to modify several parameters in a script, so I am wondering if I can do a faster way.